# How to make use of onclick when using setAttribute in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the below piece of code

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open((window.pageViewer &amp;&amp; pageViewer.link || function(link){return link;})(this.href + (this.href.indexOf('?')>=0 ? '&amp;' : '?') + 'url=' + escape(document.location.href)), 'Chat000', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=640,height=480');return false;">
```

I need to implement the same with JavaScript/DOM elements. I am not allowed to write html directly. So I may have to make use of `document.createElement`.

Can I use as below ?

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('onclick',"window.open((window.pageViewer &amp;&amp; pageViewer.link || function(link){return link;})(this.href + (this.href.indexOf('?')>=0 ? '&amp;' : '?') + 'url=' + escape(document.location.href)), 'Chat000', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=640,height=480');return false;");
```

Will this code work ? If not, how to do it ?

Comment: @JacquesMarais jsfiddle.net, not .org.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You can test it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) to see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will works in certain browser, but not in all browsers. Some version of IE, for instance, doesn't bind properly the "attributes" with the "properties". So depends by the browsers you want to support, there is a chance that `setAttribute` actually won't set the click listener. That's why the best thing to do, is set by javascript, that has a broader compatibility:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.onclick = function(event) {
    window.open(/*.. your params  **/);
    return false;
}
```

This is basically what is happening when you set an `onclick` attribute, if the browser bind properly the attribute: so, from a functionality point of view, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks ! So, instead of using a.setAttribute, I should use a.onclick. Doesn't that make sense ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: a.onclick = function(event) {
window.open((window.pageViewer &amp;&amp; pageViewer.link || function(link){return link;})(this.href + (this.href.indexOf('?')>=0 ? '&amp;' : '?') + 'url=' + escape(document.location.href)), 'Chat367233609785093432', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=640,height=480');
return false;
};

This is showing some syntax error. I don't understand. Can u help me ?

Comment: That's because you have `&amp;` instead of just `&`. Here you are in a full JS context, so you don't need to escape any entity character, you can write simply JS. So, for instace, instead of `&amp;&amp;` you will have `&&`.

Comment: Thanks much !! Not showing syntax errors now.